# Ansible password_hash wont' use bcrypt even though passlib is installed

Tags: python, ansible, bcrypt

I'm trying to call Ansible's `password_hash` function thusly...

```
{{ admin_password | password_hash('bcrypt') }}
```

and I've tried a dozen ways to tell Ansible where passlib and python 2.7 are but no matter what, I'm continuously getting the result...

```
"AnsibleFilterError: crypt.crypt does not support 'bcrypt' algorithm"
```

From what I can see, ansible used to only use `crypt`, but newer versions (I'm currently on 2.7.9) use `passlib` when it's there and passlib supports bcrypt as far as I understand (which is limited).  I've added the following to my hosts file...

```
ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I'm installing PIP and Passlib like so...

```
- name: Install PY stuff...
  yum: 
    name: ['python2-pip','python2-passlib']
    state: present

- name: Ensure bcrypt support is installed for python passlib
  pip:
   name: "passlib[bcrypt]"
   executable: pip-2.7
```

I would have expected the yum call to get passlib set up properly but it didn't work, so then I tried doing only via PIP, it didn't work either, so then I tried the above which still isn't working. I wasn't sure whether passlib included bcrypt when installed via yum, because it doesn't when using only PIP it seems, so just in case, I did both.  No joy.

I should add that I'm in AWS on Amazon Linux 2, and I've enabled the epel repo, etc.

---

EDIT: I've tried several of the suggestions from comments (using passlib 1.6, validating that bcrypt works with python) and while I can verify that passlib does work when testing within python, but I continue to get the same answer from Ansible `AnsibleFilterError: crypt.crypt does not support 'bcrypt' algorithm`

The only thing I've found relating to this is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17266 but it describes the default it to look for passlib and only fallback on crypt.crypt when it's not present. So why does python see passlib when I run it manually, but not from the playbook?

Comment: For the record. Exactly the same problem with Ubuntu was solved with the installation of "*python-passlib*".

Comment: @VladimirBotka Do you mean instead of `python2-passlib`? Isn't that for a lesser version of Python?  Do you have a link to anything I can read related to what you mean?

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04, ansible 2.7.9 and python 2.7.15rc1 the [test playbook](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-076/test1.yml) reported *"AnsibleFilterError: crypt.crypt does not support 'bcrypt' algorithm"*. The problem was solved by the installation of "python-passlib". There was no python2-passlib.

Comment: @VladimirBotka tried removing passlib 1.7 and forcing the install of the "obsoleted" 1.6 but no difference.  Worked it into the playbook just in case a fresh install without 1.7 in the picture might make a difference but no joy.  Same error from Ansible, and same result as described in my comments to '@'larsks below.

Comment: YMMV with Amazon Linux 2. The intention of my 1st comment "For the record" is to inform Ubuntu users who find this thread. I think you'll have to bring the issue to an appropriate Amazon Linux forum.

Answer (score 11):

First, verify that Ansible is using the Python you think it is.  Look at `head -1 $(which ansible)`, and you should see something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

Ensure that you've installed `passlib` where that Python can find it:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2
Python 2.7.15 (default, Oct 15 2018, 15:24:06) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import passlib
>>>
```

I'm using Fedora 28, so I was able to simply `yum -y install
python2-passlib`.

Ensure that `passlib` has support for `bcrypt`:

```
>>> from passlib.hash import bcrypt
>>> bcrypt.hash('secret')
'$2b$12$3YUj4BgoJ8ba1H4XtH/p3.4DG0lMgaHQ4qYshpj/.COe1eHEU.71K'
>>>
```

If all of the above are successful, the `password_hash` filter should
work:

```
$ cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ 'secret' | password_hash('bcrypt') }}"

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "$2b$12$H9rnvJwYtSoy05WHMYuJR.Kaz9kxLJleT7XUsIauWwd3Mdk0H/Kl6"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Very much appreciate the detailed answer and debug playbook, will give that a shot.

Comment: So, everything seemed to check out up to the point where I tested the ansible debug, where the value of "msg" was empty.  No error like I'm getting when running my full playbooks from the controller, but no output either.  No extra details using -vvvv either, looks like it's using correct python.  Any ideas?

Comment: Would it make a difference if the call to `password_hash` is in a template? Might the call be made on the controller rather than the host?

Answer (score 7):

Google pointed out this question when I faced a problem using bcrypt in Jinja2 template.

```
{{ k }}: {{ v | password_hash('bcrypt')}}
```

was returning:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Like a lot of people I've installed "passlib" but it was still not working. What did I do wrong? You have to install "passlib" on your local controller and not on remote host!

Hope it could help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install passlib` 
or try **specify ident**: `2a$12`, `'2b$12'`, ...
`{{ 'PaSsword' | password_hash('bcrypt', ident='2b$12') }}` 
tested on `Python 3.10.8`, `ansible [core 2.13.0]` 
`libpython3.x-stdlib` on Ubuntu or 
`python3-libs` on CentOS must be installed 
check `python3 -c 'import crypt; print("OK")'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).